# C# BindingSource DataTable を使ったDataGridViewのデータ削除方法教えてください

Tags: c#, winforms

以下のようにDataGridViewのDataSourceにBindingSourceを
設定してBindingSourceのDataSourceにDataTableを
設定してFormのDataGridViewを構築した場合の
DataGridViewのデータ削除方法を教えてください。
今一うまくいかずはまっております。。
初歩的な質問かもしれませんがご教示頂きたく
よろしくお願いいたします。

以下ソースを簡略化した例となります。

```
public partial class HogeForm : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    private void InitDataGridView()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("hoge");
        this.bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
        this.dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;

        DataTable table = 
          ((DataView)((BindingSource)this.dataGridView.DataSource).List).ToTable();
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        ~~rowにデータを設定(省略)~~
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        this.bindingSource.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void ClearDataGridView()
    {
         ?? <- DataGridViewの内容をクリアするにはどうすればよいですか？
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にデータを消す場合は以下の通りです。

```
((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Clear();
```

なお質問のコードは`ToTable()`でデータを作成しているので当てはまらないと思いますが、削除ではなく削除状態にする場合は

```
foreach (var dr in ((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray())
{
    dr.Delete();
}
```

のように各行の状態を変更します。

Comment: *DataTable.Clear()を使用するとDataTable.Columnsもクリアされてしまう* ということはないのでは。

Comment: @Ripple すみません、勘違いがあったようです。

Comment: ((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).Clear();
で解決できました。
bindingSource.DataSourceでDataTableを取得するのがみそですね。